# Variable display on textbBox forms c#

Tags: c#, forms, variables, textbox, calculator

So I'm making a simple calculator and I'm using windows forms on c#.
I would like to know how I can permanently display a zero "0" on the textBox... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form load add

```
textBox1.Text="0";
```

Answer (score 1):

In the properties window of the control, set the Text to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the 'text' property of the text box to zero either through the property manager or through the code. However, if you want to always have the value be zero, you should also set the read-only property of the textbox so a user can't change it.

You also may want to look into the label control if there will be never be any user editing of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Textbox1.Text = 0;
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = True;
    }
```